# A solution for "out of memory" error in matlab

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory

i have a very big size of text file(about 11GB) that needs to load in matlab.but when i use "textread" function,"out of memory" error occurs.and There is no way to reduce the file size. when i type memory, show this to me.

```
memory
Maximum possible array:     24000 MB (2.517e+10 bytes) *
Memory available for all arrays:     24000 MB (2.517e+10 bytes) *
Memory used by MATLAB:      1113 MB (1.167e+09 bytes)
Physical Memory (RAM):     16065 MB (1.684e+10 bytes)

*  Limited by System Memory (physical + swap file) available.
```

Does anyone have a solution to this problem?

Comment: You could try reading the file [line by line](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/71374-how-to-read-a-text-file-line-by-line#answer_81658). What kind of data is in the text file, and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: Buy more RAM I guess....

Comment: @Ander You need to start taking referral $$$ from Corsair for the consistent "buy more RAM" commenting on "out of memory" questions!

Comment: @rinkert  it is a point cloud with XYZRGB column in txt file and i needs to add another column to this. how can i read this line by line?

Comment: @Wolfie what other solution there is.... if the entire variable is required and it does not fit in memory, thats the solution.... Otherwise, restructure the entire code also works. I'd should contact Corsair :P

Comment: See the link in my comment, if the column you need to add is not dependent on all the data, but only one or maybe a couple of lines, you could write the updated line with the new column to a new text file. Can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55846862/edit) you question and show how this new column has to be made.

Answer (score 5):

@Anthony suggested a way to read the file line-by-line, which is perfectly fine, but more recent (>=R2014b) versions of MATLAB have [`datastore`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datastore.html) functionality, which is designed for processing large data files in chunks.

There are several types of `datastore` available depending on the format of your text file. In the simplest cases (e.g. CSV files), the automatic detection works well and you can simply say

```
ds = datastore('myCsvFile.csv');
while hasdata(ds)
    chunkOfData = read(ds);
    ... compute with chunkOfData ...
end
```

In even more recent (>=R2016b) versions of MATLAB, you can go one step further and wrap your `datastore` into a [`tall`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tall.tall.html) array. `tall` arrays let you operate on data that is too large to fit into memory all at once. (Behind the scenes, `tall` arrays perform computations in chunks, and give you the results only when you ask for them via a call to `gather`). For example:

```
tt = tall(datastore('myCsvFile.csv'));
data = tt.SomeVariable;
result = gather(mean(data)); % Trigger tall array evaluation
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your clarification of the purpose of your code:

> it is a point cloud with XYZRGB column in txt file and i needs to add another column to this.

What I suggest you to do is read the text file one line at a time, modify the line and write the modified line straight to a new text file.

To read one line at a time:

```
% Open file for reading.
fid = fopen(filename, 'r');

% Get the first line.
line = fgetl(fid);
while ~isnumeric(line)
    % Do something.

    % get the next line
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
```

To write the line, you can use `fprintf`.

Here is a demonstration:

```
filename = 'myfile.txt';
filename_new = 'myfile_new.txt';

fid = fopen(filename);
fid_new = fopen(filename_new,'w+');
line = fgetl(fid);
while ~isnumeric(line)
    % Make sure you add \r\n at the end of the string; 
    % otherwise, your text file will become a one liner.
    fprintf(fid_new, '%s %s\r\n', line, 'new column');
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
fclose(fid);
fclose(fid_new);
```

Comment: thank you, i tested this code too, but in the "while" loop also out of memory occurred.

Comment: @shima that sounds weird, since nothing in the `while` loop is sending large data to memory. In your test code, have you add some other code in the loop?